# How to convert flv to avi using ffmpeg high quality

Tags: linux, flash, video, ffmpeg, flash-video

Need to convert flv files to avi or mov, trying out ffmpeg but the output quality is terrible. How can I get the video output to be on par quality with the source?

I thought ffmpeg -i name.flv -s 320x... name.avi would do it, but no good.

Answer (score 30):

That's the command I was using for a ffmpeg project, the quality should be good enough. If not, try increasing the bitrate (`-b` argument):

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ar 22050 -b 2048k output.avi
```

Comment: it tells me `-b` is ambiguous. Use `-b:v` or `-b:a` instead. What's this?

Comment: @OptimusPrime: that's the video/audio bitrate respectively (if anyone else was also confused).

Comment: But the file size is so high. Anyway to reduce the file size without compramising quality. My video file mostly contains texts

Answer (score 16):

This is a Good solutions

```
ffmpeg -async 1 -i inputVideo.flv -f avi -b 700k -qscale 0 -ab 160k -ar 44100 outputVideo.avi
```

Or Used following one

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -async 1 -i inputVideo.flv -f avi -b 700k -sameq -ab 160k -ar 44100 outputVideo.avi
```

Comment: +1, the first command above is the only one that worked for me, others either had "invalid parameters" or seg faulted.

Comment: this is THE solution! ,)

Comment: +1 thanks to your second solution that I updated in `ffmpeg -i input.flv -async 1 -f avi -b 700k -qscale 0 -ab 160k -ar 44100 outputVideo.avi`. I convert a 100 mins flv video of 270mb to 1.5 GB avi file with the same quality. :)

Comment: Also works for me for avconv  -async 1 -i in.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -f avi -b 700k -qscale 0 -ab 160k -ar 44100 out2.avi

Answer (score 9):

There is also another solution found on the internet and works like charm!

Just use same quality parameter `-sameq`.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.flv -sameq outputVideo.avi
```

Actually the command sameq is not same quality.
In order to successfully do it this one must be applied:
in case you have multiple files to do here is the complete command

```
for %i in (*.flv) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -q:a 0 -q:v 0 "%i".avi
```

Comment: This does NOT mean 'same quality': http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Option%20%27-sameq%27%20does%20NOT%20mean%20%27same%20quality%27

Comment: "Option 'sameq' was removed. If you are looking for an option to preserve the quality (which is not what -sameq was for), use -qscale 0 or an equivalent quality factor option."

Comment: `-q:a 0 -q:v 0` is the answer in 2020

Answer (score 5):

To preserve quality use `-qscale 0`.

For example `ffmpeg.exe -i InputVid.avi -qscale 0 OutputVid.mp4`

I converted my 1.64 GB avi video to 4.35 MB mp4 file.

Comment: `-qscale` is ignored by libx264 which, if available, is the default encoder for MP4 output. Use `-crf` instead if using this encoder. Since it is ignored I'll assume the default of `-crf 23` was applied in your case.